# "Division by zero"/ NULL values TF-IDF

Tags: php, laravel, machine-learning, tf-idf, php-ml

I'm trying to test tf-idf package from PHP-ML, I tried using their documentation code but it keeps giving me "Division by zero" when I try to use different samples(strings).

```
use Phpml\FeatureExtraction\TfIdfTransformer;

$samples = [
    ["Tareq", "Tareq", "Tareq"],
    ["Mohammad", "Ahmad", "Tareq"]
];

$transformer = new TfIdfTransformer($samples);
dd($transformer);
```

And when I try using transform method from the example provide in their docs

```
 $samples = [
            [1, 2, 4],
            [0, 2, 1]
        ];

$transformer = new TfIdfTransformer($samples);
$transformer->fit($samples);
dd($transformer->transform($samples));
```

it gives me NULL.

Tfdftransformer.php :

```
            <?php

    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Phpml\FeatureExtraction;

    use Phpml\Transformer;

class TfIdfTransformer implements Transformer
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $idf = [];

public function __construct(array $samples = [])
{
    if (count($samples) > 0) {
        $this->fit($samples);
    }
}

public function fit(array $samples, ?array $targets = null): void
{
    $this->countTokensFrequency($samples);

    $count = count($samples);
    foreach ($this->idf as &$value) {
        $value = log((float) ($count / $value), 10.0);
    }
}

public function transform(array &$samples): void
{
    foreach ($samples as &$sample) {
        foreach ($sample as $index => &$feature) {
            $feature *= $this->idf[$index];
        }
    }
}

private function countTokensFrequency(array $samples): void
{
    $this->idf = array_fill_keys(array_keys($samples[0]), 0);

    foreach ($samples as $sample) {
        foreach ($sample as $index => $count) {
            if ($count > 0) {
                ++$this->idf[$index];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: update your question with the transformer class

Comment: I've updated it

Comment: try this if($value>0) { $value = log((float) ($count / $value), 10.0);} in fit() function

Comment: That fixes the division by zero problem, but it still gives NULL... Any idea how this package works? The documentation is so bad... https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/feature-extraction/tf-idf-transformer/